# Azure Client READ/WRITE permissions

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to create a vm using Azure client, I already created the subscription, the App and the Resource Group, I added Owner, Developper Role assignement in the App to the tenant account and created the Client with a secret client.

```
ComputeManager computeManager = ComputeManager
            .authenticate(
                    new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
                            .clientSecret("hidden-ky")
                            .clientId("hidden-92")
                            .tenantId("hidden-1b")
                            .build(),
                    new AzureProfile("hidden-1b", "hidden-43", AzureEnvironment.AZURE));
    VirtualMachine virtualMachine = computeManager.virtualMachines()
            .define("s")
            .withRegion(Region.US_WEST)
            .withExistingResourceGroup("RG1")
            .withNewPrimaryNetwork("10.0.0.0/28")
            .withPrimaryPrivateIPAddressDynamic()
            .withoutPrimaryPublicIPAddress()
            .withPopularLinuxImage(KnownLinuxVirtualMachineImage.UBUNTU_SERVER_18_04_LTS)
            .withRootUsername("name")
            .create();

Exception in thread "main" com.azure.core.management.exception.ManagementException: Status code 403, "{"error":{"code":"AuthorizationFailed","message":"The client 'hidden-d1' with object id 'hidden-d1' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/write' over scope '/subscriptions/hidden-43/resourceGroups/RG1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet51543c6717' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials."}}": The client 'hidden-d1' with object id 'hidden-d1' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/write' over scope '/subscriptions/hidden-43/resourceGroups/RG1/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/vnet51543c6717' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

Comment: What RBAC roles are assigned to your Service Principal?

Comment: Microsoft.Network.*

Answer (score 0):

> The client 'xxx' with object id 'xxx' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/write' over scope
> '/subscriptions/xxx/resourceGroups/xxx/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/testruknet' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.

I agree with @*Gaurav Mantri,* the error usually occurs if the Service Principal doesn't have the required permissions to perform the action.

When I tried to create Virtual Network via REST API using Service Principal, I got the same error as you:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/testruknet?api-version=2022-11-01

{
"properties": {
"addressSpace": {
"addressPrefixes": [
"10.0.0.0/16"
]
},
"flowTimeoutInMinutes": 10
},
"location": "westus"
}
```

[image]

In my case, I assigned **Network Contributor role** to the Service Principal like below:

[image]

After assigning the role, **I am able to create the Virtual Network successfully** like below:

[image]

**In your scenario**, please check under what scope you have assigned the role.

- Make sure the Virtual Network you got in the error exists under the resource group.
- Make sure the **owner role** is assigned to the Service Principal under right scope where you are trying to create Virtual machine.
- If you created any custom role, make sure to add permission **`Microsoft.Network/*`**.
- After assigning the role to the Service Principal there might be some delay so try after few minutes.

I assigned the **owner role to the Service Principal** under resource group scope like below:

[image]

I am able to **create the Virtual Machine successfully** via REST API like below:

```json
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvmruk?api-version=2023-03-01

{
"location": "westus",
"properties": {
"hardwareProfile": {
"vmSize": "Standard_D2s_v3"
},
"storageProfile": {
"imageReference": {
"sku": "18.04-LTS",
"publisher": "Canonical",
"version": "latest",
"offer": "UbuntuServer"
},
"osDisk": {
"caching": "ReadWrite",
"managedDisk": {
"storageAccountType": "Premium_LRS"
},
"name": "myVMosdisk",
"createOption": "FromImage"
}
},
"osProfile": {
"adminUsername": "rukmini",
"computerName": "testvmruk",
"adminPassword": "xxx",
"linuxConfiguration": {
"provisionVMAgent": true,
"patchSettings": {
"assessmentMode": "ImageDefault"
}
}
},
"networkProfile": {
"networkInterfaces": [
{
"id": "/subscriptions/SubID/resourceGroups/RG/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/testrukk",
"properties": {
"primary": true
}
}
]
}
}
}
```

[image]

**Reference:**

[Azure built-in roles - Azure RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles#compute)